# formData not working: after append, I got empty form data

Tags: angular, form-data

I am trying to send formData using below code but when I console formData I am getting empty formData.

I am beginner. Why is this happening?

Here I am logging formdata:

**FormData {}**

Code:

```
  onSubmit () {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', this.blogForm.get('title').value);
        formData.append('description', this.blogForm.get('description').value);
        formData.append('is_featured', this.blogForm.get('is_featured').value);
        formData.append('is_active', this.blogForm.get('is_active').value);
        formData.append('image', this.blogForm.get('image').value);

    console.log(formData);
    
     this.blogService.createBlog(formData).subscribe(
            res => {
              if (!res) {
                this.uploadError = "Error occured";
              } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/admin/blogs']);
              }
            },
            error => this.error = error
          );
    
    createBlog(blog) {
        return this.http.post<Blog>(this.serverUrl + 'admin-blog-list', blog)
          .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
          );
      }
```

Comment: Hello abhi ram i will help you with can you please and this into stackbiz

Comment: sorry its big module and i clearly mentioned my code above

Comment: Ok fine then you please tell me few things or start conversation with me

Comment: BTW, why not simply: `this.blogService.createBlog(this.blogForm.value).subscribe(...)`? it's not necessary use a FormData. NOTE: If you function createBlog transform the data you can pass a "copy", e.g. if you has an object with properties that are string or numbers, using the spread operator: `this.blogService.createBlog({...this.blogForm.value}).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Since **formData** is an object, in order to access its values you must use

```
console.log(formData.get('title'))

for (var key of formData.keys()) {
 console.log(key); 
}

for (var value of formData.values()) {
 console.log(value); 
}
```

please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: 'getKeys' does not exist on type 'FormData'.

Comment: can you try this
for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Hi abhi i am not sure about     this.blogForm.get(*).value that you getting or not but if getting your value then please try now with thing will work

```
onSubmit () {

           //Change this of code 

            let formdata: FormData = new FormData();

            formData.append('title', this.blogForm.get('title').value);
            formData.append('description', this.blogForm.get('description').value);
            formData.append('is_featured', this.blogForm.get('is_featured').value);
            formData.append('is_active', this.blogForm.get('is_active').value);
            formData.append('image', this.blogForm.get('image').value);

        console.log(formData);

         this.blogService.createBlog(formData).subscribe(
                res => {
                  if (!res) {
                    this.uploadError = "Error occured";
                  } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/admin/blogs']);
                  }
                },
                error => this.error = error
              );

        createBlog(blog) {
            return this.http.post<Blog>(this.serverUrl + 'admin-blog-list', blog)
              .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError)
              );
          }
```

If still not working let me know

Comment: console.log('Data is--->'+JSON.stringify(formdata)); getting empty object

Comment: this.blogForm.get(*).value i am getting values

Comment: Can you please check console once ?

Comment: What console you talking about abhi ram

Comment: console.log(formData); Tell me about this